# How to add more Ad creatives to ads By Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

everyone.
I just want to ask an question.
Im using the Facebook Marketing API Java SDK.

```
            AdCreative adCreative = new AdAccount(ExampleConfig.ACCOUNT_ID, context).createAdCreative()
                            .setName(adname)
                            .setObjectStorySpec(
                                    new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec()
                                            .setFieldLinkData(
                                                    new AdCreativeLinkData()
                                                            .setFieldCaption(textcontent)
                                                            .setFieldChildAttachments(attachments))
                                            .setFieldPageId(strPageId)
                            )
                            .execute();


            Ad ad = account.createAd()
                    .setName(adname)
                    .setAdsetId(Long.parseLong(adset.getId()))
                    .setCreative(adCreative)
                    .setStatus(Ad.EnumStatus.VALUE_ACTIVE)
                    .execute();
```

You can see that,I can only set a creative,how to set many creatives?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hej,

An ad can only have 1 ad creative.
If You want to use more than 1 ad creative, you need to create more than 1 ad.

You can use the same ad creative for several ads (eg for different ad sets) but 1 ad can't have several ad creatives.